# Redirect Rule htaccess WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Hi I want to redirect URLs from `/search/label/anything` to `/search/anything`

I am new to redirects, I know it may be simple.

Another problem, I want to redirect specific URL which is `/search/label/اضافات بلوجر` to `/blogger`

the URL contains 2 Arabic words with a space separating them.

I tried this Rule but It does not work:

```
Redirect 301 /search/label/اضافات بلوجر https://mobtakr.com/blogger/
```

Any solutions?
Thank you in advance

Comment: That you can not just use a space in a parameter value, when several parameters get separated from each other by a space character to begin with, should be pretty obvious. The examples for the directive in the manual show, that these values can be put into double quotes though.

Comment: Please try using RedirectMatch 301 (.*)/source_url/$ target_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I want to add it for anyone that will have the same problem.

To redirect from `/search/label/اضافات بلوجر` to `/blogger`, I have used `RedirectMatch` with this regular expression `اضافات\sبلوجر`,

The final redirect rule is as follows:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /search/label/اضافات\sبلوجر https://mobtakr.com/blogger/
```

And to redirect URLs from /search/label/anything to /search/anything
I have used this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /search/label/([^/]+) https://mobtakr.com/search/$1
```

the regex `[^/]+` simply matches anything that is not a slash.

So, Hope this is helpful to you.